# I need an explanation on: passing argument 1 of ‘sscanf’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, gcc

This is an example of the part of the code that I'm having an error on:

```c
int cat = 0;
int red;
char abc[100];

fgets(abc, 100, stdin);
sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &cat);
sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &red);
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sscanf’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
         sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &cat);
note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 extern int __REDIRECT_NTH (sscanf, (const char *__restrict __s,
```

The definition of my `main()` function is the following one:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    /* ... */
}
```

What does it mean by passing argument 1 of ‘sscanf’ from incompatible pointer type? How can I go by fixing it?

Comment: If your main function arguments are correct there is nothing wrong with sscanf, the first argument of fgets however is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I had to rewrite the code and didn't realize I wrote char instead of abc. But is the fgets still the issue?

Comment: Did you define `int main(int argc, char **argv)`?

Comment: Post definition of `argv`.

Comment: Yes, I did define the main function with that command line but instead with char **argv[] instead of char **argv

Comment: @untraditionalprogrammer `char **argv` is equivalent to `char *argv[]`, not `char **argv[]`.

Comment: "with char \*\*argv[] instead of char \*\*argv" <== **this is the problem**. Use `char **argv` or `char *argv[]`

Comment: Thank you @RohanBari its solved, I've been using **argv for a while, so I didn't know that can't be used

Answer (score 1):

Your comment:

> Yes, I did define the main function with that command line but instead with `char **argv[]` instead of `char **argv`

No, the syntax:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[])
```

It's totally invalid. You should use:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

instead. This syntax is equivalent to:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to watch out for issues like that

Comment: @untraditionalprogrammer `char **argv` states *the pointer to the pointer variable* `argv`.